# content and excerpt not displaying

Tags: the-content, excerpt

I am using `get_the_title(453)` and while the title displays, i am unable to display the content and the excerpt for the page with the id of 453. The following is my code

```
        get_the_title(453); 
    $content = get_the_content();
    echo $content;
    the_excerpt();
```

Is there is something i am missing or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself and it worked. Here is the code if anyone need any help.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query('page_id=1') ;
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
        the_excerpt();
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

---

Edit:

This is working because `the_content()` and `the_excerpt()` have to be used within [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Answer (score 0):

get_the_title will only retrieve the title of the post you designate. That post data will not carry on to other template tags.

Edit: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post should help.

```
<?php           
 $post_id = 73;
 $queried_post = get_post(69060);
?>
<h1><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?>
<p><?php echo $queried_post->post_content; ?></p>
```

Comment: it didn't work.

Comment: And it clobbers the main query. Please, please everyone... stop using `query_posts`.

Comment: s_ha_dum is right. You should always avoid using query_posts. See here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/38536

Comment: [And here:](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/21376)

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to output only specific page title and content with looping, it is ok, you just only need id of post or page
// Here is two thing you just need to understand 
1. the_title() ( no need "echo", this function is more specific for title of current view post or page);
2. get_the_title( need "echo", this function can show every post or page title in every page);

```
use 
echo get_the_title(120); // 120 is your post or page id, it can show every page
echo get_the_title($post->ID); // for only current page view
echo get_the_title(get_the_ID()); // for only current page view, also in loop
echo get_the_title(get_the_ID(12)) //120 is your post or page id, it can show every page
echo get_the_title(get_the_ID($post->ID));


content
the_content() is only for current page, also in loop, no need echo 

echo get_the_content(120); // 120 is your post or page id, it can show every page
echo get_the_content($post->ID); // for only current page view
echo get_the_content(get_the_ID()); // for only current page view, also in loop
echo get_the_content(get_the_ID(12)) //120 is your post or page id, it can show every page
echo get_the_content(get_the_ID($post->ID));
```